# Does nutation require $n \ge 2r$?

Tags: kinematics, orbital-motion, planets, spacetime-dimensions, precession

---

I'll start of with my (mis)understanding:

We have a planet orbiting around another body. The orbiting planet has infinitely many axes passing through it, but we're interested in two, $A_1$ and $A_2$. $A_1$ is the axis that is perpendicular to the planet's orbit, whereas $A_2$ is the one passing through its poles.

The planet is rotating around $A_1$. When $A_2$ is exactly superimposable onto $A_1$, then this is a rotation without precession. If $A_2$ is at an angle from $A_1$ however, we've got precession. Let's say that the point at the tip of $A_2$ is called $a_2$. When there is no nutation, $a_2$ orbits around $A_1$ in some elliptical path.

When there is nutation, then the that orbit is disturbed in a specific way. Let's define an abstract point, $p$, that orbits around $A_1$ identically to how $a_2$ would, if there was no nutation. So, the way I've understood nutation is that it's when $a_2$ orbits around $p$.
[image]

[image]

In the lower left, you see the orbit of $a_2$ around $p$ quite clearly. However, that is a contrived scenario where $p$ isn't moving. Thing is, $p$ is in orbit around $A_2$, which means that circle gets stretched out into a $2$D helix. We could make it into a $3$D helix by defining an axis $t$, and define integer values of $t$ as the time taken for $a_2$ to orbit around $p$ once. If you look at the first photo, that time step is demarcated onto the helix.

In [this Math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4356146/how-to-make-a-looping-b%C3%A9zier-curve), I defined a function, $_rF_n(t)$, that gives us the coordinates that trace out the movement of $a_2$. It takes $t$ as the input, and outputs a two-dimensional value, corresponding to where $a_2$ exists at time $t$. If one looked at this function, it would be a $3$D helix. However, one could look at that $\Bbb R^3$ space in such a way so as to compress it into two dimensions. Basically, you position the observer's line of sight perpendicular to the $t$-axis (the $x$-axis in this photo).
[image: 2D helix]

And this get's you the path traced out by a point orbiting around another point that is moving. The above picture was taken from user65203's answer to [this Math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2216407/equation-of-a-2d-helix). Now, in the second photo of this post, I defined $r$ as the distance between $a_2$ and $p$. Now, if $p$ moves a distance $\ge 2r$ per time step, that means that there will be no looping (by loops, I mean the loops you see in the above $2$D helix). When the velocity of $p$ exceeds $2r$ per time step $t$, you get a sinusoidal wave as the curve traced out by the movement of $a_2$. The reason is that $p$ moves too fast for $a_2$ to loop back on itself, for a lack of more precise wording. In other words, by the time $a_2$ has finished its orbit, $p$ has moved a distance of $2r$, thus meaning it has no chance of crossing over a point is has been before. To illustrate this, let me show the middle point between $n = 0$ and $n = 2r$, $n$ being the distance travelled by $p$ per time step $t$.
[image]

Here, $n = r$.

---

The question:

The thing is, whenever I look at pictures where nutation is illustrated, the path of $a_2$ never loops; it's sinusoidal (see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nutation) for an example). So, that makes me think that nutation for some reason requires $n \ge 2r$. However, this belief is based on my current (mis)understanding. So, this leaves me with two questions:

1. Is my understanding correct?
2. If so, why is $n \ge 2r$?

---

Answer (score 0):

I will give links to resources that I think will be of help to you.

(The stackexchange policy is that contributors should given standalone answers, using links only for corroboration. I support that policy, but writing a standalone answer here would be very time consuming.)

**Experimental**

Svilen Kostov and Daniel Hammer have conducted a tabletop experiment to verify experimentally that the *onset* of gyroscopic precession always involves nutation. (Generally the nutation dampens out quickly. Faster spin rate corresponds to faster nutation rate, and smaller nutation amplitude. In classroom demonstations: when the spin rate is fast the nutation generally goes unnoticed, and it rapidly dampens out.)

The title of their article is: [It has to go down a little, in order to go around](https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.5288)

**Theoretical**

There is a set of two articles by Eugene Butikov

About torque-free precession (also known as Feynman's wobbling plate):
Eugene Butikov "inertial rotation of a rigid body"

(I googled that title, and was able to obtain the article from the website researchgate.net, without having to create an account.)

Butikov points out that there is a particular way of representing the motion of torque-free precession geometrically. The motion of the axis of the wobbling body is moving in the way a cone rolls inside a wider cone.

The follow-up article applies the concepts laid out in the preceding article, presenting discussion of connection between nutation and precession:
Eugene Butikov "Precession and nutation of a gyroscope"